# Minute counter in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make a counter for 1 minute, or display elapsed time in seconds and minutes.

This is the code I'm using but it is not showing the time, just zeros.

```
char str[200];

double t = (double)getTickCount();

t = ((double)getTickCount() - t) / getTickFrequency();

sprintf(str, "%f  detection time", t);

putText(matCapturedImage, str, Point2f(100, 100), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 0.7, Scalar(0, 0, 255, 255));`
```

Comment: Can you include a complete example?

Comment: calling `getTickCount` twice with no code in between them is likely to give you the same amount of ticks.

Comment: the code i"m using is very long , I just put the relevant part

Comment: Then can you include a more complete example?

Comment: The example code you've given is more-or-less guaranteed to produce zeros. You'll need to show some portion of your code or boil it down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NathanOliver That's the correct answer, do you care to type it up?

Comment: @JonathanMee I was kinda hoping the OP would come back and confirm if those two lines are actually ran back to back or if they cut out code to make it minimal.  Not really sure which way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
double t = (double)getTickCount();
double time=0;
for(;;)
{
   time = ((double)getTickCount() - t) / getTickFrequency();
   /*t is not updated but getTickCount() is*/
   if(time>=60.0)
     {
        t = (double)getTickCount();
        /*This resets t back to latest tick count and time back to zero*/
     }
}
```